# Where can i find the full list of functions, for aggfunc in pandas.pivot_table?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, pivot-table

Im trying to find a list of functions for the "aggfunc" parameter. 
Where can i find this list or url?

Comment: Thanks for answering, but is there is somewhere a list of the parameter aggfunc that cames included in pandas? It's for a work so i cannot and numpy to the work :p.

Comment: As `aggfunc` accepts custom functions there can't be an exhaustive list. Perhaps [this](https://cmdlinetips.com/2019/10/pandas-groupby-13-functions-to-aggregate/) helps for 'named' functions but they give no source. And they are missing for example `cumsum` and `cumprod`.

Comment: What do you mean by *i cannot and numpy to the work*? `numpy` is included in and a dependency of `pandas`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.